# Make div onclick event work instead of buttons and checkboxes inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a checkbox inside it, and the checkbox does not work by itself (it is triggered by the div onclick), I want to make it so that clicking anywhere on the div (including the checkbox, or a button too, the onclick event of the div gets called instead of the button/checkbox). Kinda like a z-index but for javascript?

Comment: so you are reinventing the label

Comment: @epascarello but when I use labels, clicking on the checkbox works too, here the checkbox is disabled and thats why I want the div's onclick event to be triggered

Comment: Why checkbox is disabled I don't understand @SomeName? You can easily do it with label+checkbox combo element. In case you need help with code, reply on the thread.

Comment: What you probably want to do is avoid the event triggered by the checkbox, try it disabling by css pointer-events: none;

Comment: @GabrielMartinezBustos Thanks! this does work for me, could you answer my question so that I can accept it please

Comment: @SomeName you don't need this `<div class="dabba">`, change for a `label` and remove the `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is avoid the event triggered by the checkbox, try disabling it by css `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 2):

Use a label

```css
.product {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.product label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <label><span>Product 1</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="p1" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <label><span>Product 2</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="p2" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <label><span>Product 3</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="p3" />
  </label>
</div>
```

another variation

```css
.product {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.product input {
  display: none;
}

.product label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product input:checked + label {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <input type="checkbox" id="p1" />
  <label for="p1">Product 1</label>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <input type="checkbox" id="p2" />
  <label for="p2">Product 2</label>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <input type="checkbox" id="p3" />
  <label for="p3">Product 3</label>
</div>
```